# Unable to upgrade 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, scripts, downloads, unattended-upgrades

I tried probably all suggestions brought forward. Just want to upgrade. Why can't they give us a extended chance to upgrade with the Software Updater. Can one upgrade by downloading 18.04 LTS and if so from where.

Comment: You can *upgrade via re-install* and not lose any data file, and have the re-install automatically re-install all *manually installed* packages you added (*if available for your new release from Ubuntu repositories*) by using a install option without format. You didn't say if you're asking about server or desktop; as system directories get erased (*prior to new install which means some server app config files need to be restored; not an issue for desktop apps*), but you should always backup before install as mistakes are easily made (key is don't format or use an option that formats)

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely download Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and install it to replace your current installation.  Considering that you've already "tried everything" - a reinstall is really the only option left when you've tried everything else.  Thankfully it's very easy to do and Canonical has made a nice [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS came out in April of 2016 and the first point release came out in July of that year. After the first point release, an upgrade is generally considered stable and the upgrade process to be clear of significant bugs.  Ubuntu support for LTS releases follows a predictable support schedule for 5 years of community support from the release date.

This gives LTS users 3 full years after the next LTS has been released to upgrade to that release.  The support window is actually so long, that before it expires, the next *next* LTS has already been released for a year, in this case 20.04.

If you would like an "extension" on your support for Ubuntu 16.04, you can sign up for [Extended Security Maintenance (ESM)](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm).  The basic level of support gives you access to updates for bug fixes and other security patches. This should be enough to help make the upgrade more successful. You can choose a paid option if you need much more help than that.

Comment: I want to download 18.04.6 LTS onto a USB stick and will be using Startup Disk Creator as per a Ubuntu Tutorial to make the Download usable on any computer with the USB stick. Would like to know which ISO file for 18.04.6 LTS to download for use on my Desktop Computer. My computer OS type 64-bit. Will be used to upgrade my system.

Comment: On the official [download page](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) there is a link to [alternative downloads](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) "for other versions of Ubuntu Desktop including torrents, the network installer, a list of local mirrors, and **past releases**" -- The download links for 18.04 as a "past release" can be found there.  The current point release for 18.04 is 18.04.6

Comment: The choices are: 18.04.6 LTS - server, 18.04.6 LTS - live server or 18.04.6 LTS - desktop. Just not sure which one to download. Desktop is 2.5GB, Server and Live server are 1.0GB

Comment: Server and live server downloads are for servers and don't contain a desktop environment or GUI applications.  Based on what you've written above I'm assuming that you would probably want to use Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted what you have tried or what error messages you have received. So all I can do is answer the question you have presented. You can absolutely still upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. I am watching the upgrade right now in a VM after cleanly installing 16.04, apt upgrading packages, rebooting and then running the update manager.

You can also reference this page which gives detailed instructions to upgrade from an EOL version to the next LTS...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

But as far as I can tell, this shouldn't be necessary right now. If something in the process isn't working, you are going to need to provide more information.